# I am trying to VIEW 4 columns from 2 different tables I have already created in Oracle Live SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, live

I want to use the VIEW command to display these 4 columns in one single schema. I have tried making a single VIEW with the first 3 columns, because they are from the the same table. Adding the one other column is where I'm struggling. I have tried the ALTER function but a VIEW schema doesn't seem to have the same edit privileges as a table would. I hope that makes sense.

```
create table PATIENTINFO (  
    PatientID       number not null,  
    FirstName       varchar2(50) not null,  
    LastName        varchar2(50) not null,  
    Address         varchar2(50),  
    City            varchar2(50),  
    State           varchar2(50),  
    ZipCode         number(5),  
    Phone           number(10) not null ,  
    Email           varchar2(50),  
    MemberID        number not null,  
    constraint  pk_departments primary key (PatientID)  
)
```

```
create table LABORDER ( 
    LabOrderNumber  number not null, 
    OrDate          date not null, 
    ReqBloodTest    varchar2(15) not null, 
    Reason          varchar(50), 
    PatientID       number not null, 
    constraint  pk_laborder primary key (LabOrderNumber), 
    constraint  fk_laborder_patientid foreign key (PatientID) 
            references PATIENTINFO (PatientID) 
)
```

```
CREATE VIEW PatientBlood AS 
      SELECT FirstName, LastName, PatientID 
      FROM PATIENTINFO
```

Comment: I was trying to use the alter function to add to the VIEW thinking of it as an object like a table, but I figured out that wouldn't work really quickly. Best approach would be make two VIEW entities and then join them? What would the command be for that?

Comment: A view is what the name says: "a view". It is just another way of representing data that is stored in your physical tables. You don't alter a view, you just recreate it with the definition you want. Make sure to use "CREATE OR REPLACE view", just "CREATE view " will not work if the view already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Write the query you want and then create a view out of it. I started by writing the query below and then prefixed it with CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW. The example below has some randomly selected columns, change it to whatever columns you need. I chose to name my columns in the view definition, you can omit that but also do a million other things as stated in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504)

Side note: don't use mixed case for identifiers like column names/table names. It is confusing. In your case it didn't matter since you didn't use quotes, so they're case insensitive and the view below will work even though the identifiers are all lower case.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW laborder_v (
  labordernumber,
  patientid,
  lastname
) AS
  SELECT o.labordernumber,
         p.patientid,
         p.lastname
    FROM laborder o
    JOIN patientinfo p ON o.patientid = p.patientid;
```

Comment: Thanks this was useful. With regards to the o.labordernumber, is the o before the period representing the table I'm pulling the information from?

Comment: the "o" and "p" are aliases for the tables laborder and patientinfo (note the "o" after laborder and the "p" after patientinfo in the FROM clause. Check https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/alias.php for more info (you want table alias)